# mysql stored procedure select and update selected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to write a stored procedure for mysql, and basicly, it will select one id, and update selected id's operationdate.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE getID(
  IN proc_intervaldate datetime
 )

 BEGIN
    DECLARE RUserID BIGINT;
    SELECT 
        UserID 
    INTO RUserID 
    FROM Tasks
    WHERE  OperationDate < proc_intervaldate
    LIMIT 1 ;

    UPDATE Tasks SET OperationDate = now() WHERE UserID = RUserID;

    SELECT RUserID ;


 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but when i use this, procedure, it will return UserID but not update, if i comment

```
SELECT RUserID
```

then, it updates, but no data returns.

Comment: Procedure has no errors. It should be working. Show some example on [*SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: yeap, procedure has no errors, just because of navicat problem.

Answer (score 1):

> when I use this, procedure, it will return `UserID` but not update, if I comment `'SELECT RUserID;'` then, it updates, but no data returns.

You can change definition of stored procedure to use an `OUT` parameter rather than just `IN`. With that, you can just capture the `OUT` value on the same `OUT` parameter, in your scripting language. Meaning you need not execute:

```
SELECT RUserID ;
```

in your stored procedure.

Change your SP definition as below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getID( IN proc_intervaldate datetime, OUT RUserID bigint )
BEGIN
    SELECT 
      UserID INTO RUserID 
    FROM Tasks
    WHERE 
      OperationDate < proc_intervaldate
    LIMIT 1 ;

    UPDATE Tasks SET OperationDate = now() WHERE UserID = RUserID;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

You can call this stored procedure like, for example, at MySQL console:

```
SET @RUserID := 0;
CALL getID( now(), @RUserID );
SELECT @RUserID;
```

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL: CALL procedure syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/call.html)

  - To get back a value from a procedure using an OUT or INOUT parameter,
    pass the parameter by means of a user variable, and then check the
    value of the variable after the procedure returns.